# How to Use Variable from Socket.io Function

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I think I've been swimming in code for too long. I am new to socket.io, node and express. Right now I have a potentiometer on the server side emitting messages and on the client side, I am receiving them in the javascript console (I am using Chrome). My goal is to have a potentiometer change the position of a slider on the HTML page, which in turn will change the frequency of an oscillator using the tone.js library.

I have made an upper limit of 200 and print anything over that. Here is a snippet of the server side, my app.js

```
cylon.robot({
    connections: {
        edison: {
            adaptor: 'intel-iot'
        }
    },
    devices: {
        button: {
            driver: 'button',
            pin: 2
        },
        sensor: {
            driver: 'analogSensor',
            pin: 0,
            upperLimit: 200,
            lowerLimit: 0
        }
    }
}).on('ready', cylonReady);
cylon.start()
// this will be called each time a socket is opened, so each client will receive their own events when buttons are pushed.
var registerSocketHandlers = function (my, socket) {
    my.button.on('push', function () {
        socket.emit('button', 'push')
    })
    my.button.on('release', function () {
        socket.emit('button', 'release')
    })
    my.sensor.on('upperLimit', function (val) {
        //console.log("Upper limit reached ===> " + val);
        socket.emit('analogSensor', val)
    });
}
```

A snippet of my Client side, index.HTML:

```
var potVal = 0;
socket.on('analogSensor', function (analogVal) {
    potVal = analogVal;
    console.log('sensor value', potVal)
});
new Interface.Slider({
    drag: function (value) {
        frequency.rampTo(value, 0.1);
    },
    start: function () {
        Tone.Master.mute = false;
    },
    end: function () {
        Tone.Master.mute = true;
    },
    name: "frequency",
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    exp: .5,
    value: potVal / 10, //original value is .5
    position: 5
});
```

I've seen questions and answers online. Mostly ones that end without resolve. I've still tried them and have tried setting up a global variable on the client side seen in the above code and swapped out values in the slider. It either causes the slider to not show up at all or doesn't have an effect on it. Any suggestions welcomed. Thank you!

Comment: It would help if you specify which variable and where in your code you have problems, is it on the client or the server? right now it is hard to tell what the problem is. I bet you can get help here if you hint us a little more.

Comment: We have built a fully functional Node.js application, [aktos-webui](https://github.com/ceremcem/aktos-website), especially suited for this kind of applications; so I'm sure I can help. But as @1cgonza stated, you should be able to say the exact problem. What did you do, what did you expect, what did you get?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. The problem is on the client side. I am looking to use the potVal variable that contains my analogSensor values to change the position of the slider. In the above code, on the client side, I have tried which is the potVal / 10. The original value of that was .5. Instead of being able to control the slider, the slider does not show up. When I nest the slider inside the socket.on function, it is created on the webpage every time a value comes from the potentiometer.

Comment: I've tried to use the potVal variable in other ways, to change the frequency of a sine wave and to change the timing in a delay function. I think my overall problem is assuming I can drop the value from my potentiometer into a variable from  within the socket.on function and use it where ever I want to. I am used to programming in Arduino and can't seem to wrap my head around how to program properly in jS using socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not related with SocketIo itself. You should update the slider whenever you got message, as demonstrated in the following code:

```
var potVal = 0; // this is useless actually 

//socket.on('analogSensor', function (analogVal) {
function dummy_socket_on_analogSensor (analogVal) {
    potVal = analogVal;
    console.log('sensor value', potVal); 
    $('#chance_slider').val(potVal);
};

// when a value is got from socket.io, this will happen: 
var i = 0; 
function simulateSocketIoMessages () {
    dummy_socket_on_analogSensor(i); 
    i += 5; 
    setTimeout(simulateSocketIoMessages, 1000); 
}
simulateSocketIoMessages();
```

Here is the working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sRbHZ/74/